# Why I cannot see the full map using react-leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I tried to create a project using react and react-leaflet, I just use the easiest example for my project but I don't see the map totally ...

Here is my code :

```
import "./styles.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMap, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And you can see the full code here :

[The full project](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-rosalind-vmot6g?file=/src/App.js:0-662)

Could you help me please ?

Comment: I think you will need to import as well the react-leaflet CSS file. import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css' try this.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work :/

Comment: well, I just fixed the problem, and the map working as expected in the demo project. the problem was that you didn't add the CSS file for the map. now I have added the style for the map. working fine !! I saved the changes on the demo hope you take alook and see it.

Comment: Could you share me the new url ? Because I don't see any changes on my project. Thank you :)

Comment: yeah sure, [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-greider-eet2jk?file=/src/styles.css)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a fixed height for the map container

```
import "./styles.css";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMap, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MapContainer
        center={[51.505, -0.09]}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```